# Partial/Selective backup/copy of a Firebird database

Tags: database, backup, firebird

I would like to backup a Firebird database but exclude certain tables from the backup, is this possible?

If not, I'd like to make a copy of the Firebird database while it's running (without doing a backup followed by a restore)

Neither gbak nor nbackup seem to support things like this, and yet we have a piece of software here in the company that can do a selective backup, I just have no idea how it works. I'd like to replicate its behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

You can export tables and queries with fbexport 
http://fbexport.sourceforge.net

Answer (score 1):

There is a new parameter named skip_d in gbak for version 3 of Firebird, and you can give regex to this parameter.

You can find detail information in [here](http://tracker.firebirdsql.org/browse/CORE-2208)

For example: gbak -b -skip_d '(table1|table2|table3)' -user ...

Answer (score 0):

gbak can only do a full database, but can run while Firebird is online.

The closest you can get to using gbak without backing up is to skip the intermediate backup file by piping gbak -B to gbak -R.  That should save some time too because both operations happen at the same time.  For example,

```
gbak -B dbhost:mydb stdout -user SYSDBA -password masterkey | gbak -R stdin /firebird/mydbcopy.fdb -user SYSDBA -password masterkey
```

Otherwise if you just want to move data you are looking at a 3rd party tool.  You could also write a procedure to utilize [ON EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE](http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq16/) to refresh your selected tables locally.  (Firebird 2.5 only)